# How to wake up an inactive AudioTracks property

Tags: javascript, audiotrack

I could obtain the correct AudioTracks.length through a button click; however, I cannot obtain it without such an action.
Please see my code below. I could obtain it at line (B) but cannot at (A). Why? How can I obtain it at (A)?
I have a faint awareness that I don't understand something fundamental, but I'm in trouble because I don't know what it is. Please help me. Thank you so much for your kindness.

**[My code]**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Please use a browser supporting AudioTracks property. See [Note] for details.</h3>
        <video id="video" controls>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4"></source >
        </video>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click (myFunction)</button>
        <script>
            console.log("(A) = " + video.audioTracks.length );// (A) = 0
            function myFunction() {
                console.log("(B) = " + video.audioTracks.length );// (B) = 2
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**[Note]**
The audioTracks property is not supported in any major browsers. It is supported in Chrome beta by enabling "enable-experimental-web-platform-features" in chrome:flags.

1. Download ***Chrome beta Version 107***.
2. Type "chrome://flags/" in the address bar to see "Experiments" page.
3. Enable "#enable-experimental-web-platform-features".

**[Reference]**
https://caniuse.com/audiotracks

Comment: Dear @Mehdi, thank you for correcting my poor writing. I think that I am able to grow with each and every favor like this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the resource is at least preloaded before you can try to read anything from it (be it `audioTracks`, but even `.duration` etc.).

So wait for either the `loadedmetadata` event, or even the `canplay` one.

```js
const vid = document.querySelector("video");
vid.onloadedmetadata = (evt) => {
  console.log(vid.audioTracks);
};
```

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Dear Kaiido,

Thank you soooooo much!
You answered my question cleary and completely!!!
What a nice professional you are.
Thanks for the superlative help!

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code, and tried running it as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Please use a browser supporting AudioTracks property. See [Note] for details.</h3>
        <video id="video" controls>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4"></source >
        </video>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click (myFunction)</button>
        <script> 
            console.log("(A)"+document.getElementById("video").audioTracks);// (A) = 0
            function myFunction() {
                console.log("(B) = " + video.audioTracks.length );// (B) = 2
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: I did not realize I had to restart my browser to initiate this effect**

@Kaiido is correct, all you need to do is wait for the metadata to load.

I changed your video element to this:

```
<video id="video" onloadedmetadata="myFunction()" controls=true>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4"></source >
</video>
```

Once the video loaded, it outputted `(B) = 2` without my having to click the button.

If you are looking to run code, waiting until it has finished loading, you can use the `onloadedmetadata` feature, or if you have a bunch of elements you need to load, you can utilize [`window.requestNewAnimationFrame(runningFunc)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to check to see if everything is loaded, or just recursively call the function until it is loaded.

I hope this answers your question, and clarifies any incorrect statements I made.

Comment: If it helps, to verify whether or not an Object has a specific property, you can do ```console.log(myObject)``` to print out the object and all of it's properties, without having to guess what is going wrong.

Comment: Dear Mr. Jacob Malland

Thank you so much for your comment. I was really happy to get a comment because I was afraid that it would go unnoticed by anyone. So, thanks!!

First, browsers supporting AudioTracks property are listed here:
https://caniuse.com/audiotracks
And Chrome beta 107 is one of them.
https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/
As you know, Chrome beta versions can set experimental features ON.
AudioTracks property is one of the experimental features.
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10612145?hl=en
See [Note] for how to set up AudioTracks property ON.

(cont.)

Comment: Using a browser supporting AudioTracks, you can correctly see this page:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_audiotracks
and correctly find what I wrote too. (cont.)

Comment: Second, your line (A) is wrong. It shoule be 
console.log("(A) = " + document.getElementById("video").audioTracks.length );

Comment: @Rio, I went to the w3schools page and ran the code snippet. I've seen it and used it myself for the controls feature before. I have the experimental features enabled on Chrome, but it still displays undefined for me, even in the other answer. From everything I've seen, it just doesn't exist on chrome.

Comment: Dear Mr. Jacob Malland, I think you brought in a great solution by Kaiido. Thank you very much. I think you are a lucky person. Thank you very much!